# subprocess.Popen sterr to string

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to call a process and output both  its stdd and stout to a string for inspection. This code  triggers the Unexpected error block.

```
try:
    proc = subprocess.Popen('ls -ddd 1>&2', stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  stderr=subprocess.PIPE,)
    stdout,stderr = proc.communicate()
    if len(stderr)>1:
        actualResult =stderr
    else:
        actualResult =stdout
    print actualResult
except:
    print "Unexpected error"
```

Ive based it on http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2007/08/pymotw_subprocess_1.html but am obviously missing something. Is it possible to do this inside a try block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never use a generic `Except` clause, as this will catch *any* exception and prevent you from fixing the script (Each and any exception is caught, so how do you know which one occured?).

Here, if you remove the Except block, you're faced with a `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. This means that `subprocess.Popen` hasn't found the executable you asked for on your path.

Which is happening because you didn't pass `shell = true` to your `Popen` call.
Not passing `shell = True` which means that `subprocess.Popen` is looking for an executable called `"ls -ddd 1>&2"`, which is equivalent to literally writing  `"ls -ddd 1>&2"` at your prompt and would result in a "command not found!"
(unless you happened to have an executable file with spaces and ampersands in the filename!)

This is of course *not* what you want, what you want is to call the `ls` command with the argument `-ddd` and redirecting `1>&2`.

---

Long story short, add `shell = True` to your call.